# Handle two structs with same members name, but different data types in C

Tags: c, struct, types, union

I have a global struct:

```
struct input_raw{
    uint8_t a;
    int16_t b;
    float32_t c;
}
```

which holds values of my inputs.
I then need to apply a polynomial transformation to such inputs, so, the data type of the transformed inputs should be float.

```
struct input_processed{
    float32_t a;
    float32_t b;
    float32_t c;
}
```

Now I wonder, what is the best way to achieve this without having to manage two different structs with the same member names, but different data types?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: type conversion. ? what is the problem to get them as `uints` and convert them to `floats` ?

Comment: C is strongly typed, so you can't have a structure that magically transforms data like that. You can use a `union` but it won't convert, it just force typecasts. You *need* a transformation function to go back and forth, or you need to make both parts of your system work on the exact same structure.

Comment: IMHO, if you have to actively perform a conversion step, having two different structs with different names is not wrong. As an alternative you could use an `union` for every field. But in any case there will be a difference in accessing them.

Comment: Use two different structs with two different structure tags. The member names can be the same.  This should be a non-issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. There is no problem in converting integers to floats, the problem is I need to store both raw data and processed data. As for the transformation function, that's exactly what the polynomial transformation does (it is a function which takes a value as input, applies a polynomial transformation and returns the calculated value as a float). I am not looking for a "magic" way to transform data, I just need a clean way to store raw and processed data, the transformation part is already done. Thank you again.

Comment: @TomKarzes thanks, but that's what I am trying to avoid. These structs have hundreds of members and I would like to avoid having to keep the two structs' members synchronized.